# Using custom fonts : digital-7 fonts for Label

Tags: iphone, fonts

Did anybody used digital-7 fonts in UILabel, i found text to align in bottom(aligns too low on the Y axis instead of being in the vertical center of the label). do anybody has solution to show them center aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about, with that particular font, is that it aligns too low on the Y axis instead of being in the vertical center of the label. Some solutions:

1. get a font manager and fix the font by hand
2. adjust the UILabel instances or a UILabel subclass to push it up higher than it is. You could do this by intercepting a `setFrame` call, for instance.

As far as I can see, UIFont does not carry that information with it at all. It might, though: [you can check some of the read-only properties of the font](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

With that said, however, you still can't **set** properties on a font, so you cannot adjust it in this way.

Comment: cn u suggest some thing more for first solution, becoz i am using the second one right now.. thanks

Comment: google "font editing software mac" or "font editing software windows" and you'll find what you need. Best!

Comment: Thanks, downloading fontforge

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
UILabel *testLabel    = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(148, 142, 130, 25)];
[testLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:20]];
[testLabel setText:@"MY Text"];
[testLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[testLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[testLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used custom fonts in my project earlier. Just you have to add the font.tff file in your project and set your font with `setFont` method